# I am getting error pathextension is unavailable use pathextension on nsurl insted

Tags: ios, nsstring

Here is my code

```
let pathVal = exportedFileURL!.path
let pathEx: String = pathVal!.pathExtension
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess exportedFileURL is an optional `NSURL`, according to the variable name.

According to [NSURL Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURL/path), the `path` property is a `String`, so you can't use it as an `NSURL` object and use the `pathExtension` property on it.

Try instead :

```
let pathEx = exportedFileURL!.pathExtension
```